# Is any way to detect when any activity of my app are displaying and when all activities are closing?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I.e I would like to know when user interact with my application and when not.

I have tried do it using ActivityManager.getRecentTasks(). I have checked root activity at a top task to detect interact user with my application or not.

I have forced to check it in separated thread each second or two.

This way is bad for me. There is another way to detect when any activity of my app are opening or closed?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) of an Activity.
There are callback methods (`onStart, onResume, onPause, onDestroy`, ...) that are invoked by the system whenever your activity is created, becomes active or inactive etc.
You might create your own application class (just inherit from `android.app.Application`) and do your tracking there. The application will be around as long as your app is running.
For example you could put a flag or a counter there and set it from the activities' callbacks. A simple example for that could be:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((MyApplication)getApplication()).active = true;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ((MyApplication)getApplication()).destroyed += 1;
}
```